# Powerful Workstation

Tags: performance, cluster

I heard about ILM's (Industrial Light and Magic) workstations on which they create models and scenes for a lot of different movies. They have workstations with more than 1024 GB of ram and a lot of CPU cores, when I remember correct. How can I do this with Ubuntu or some other Linux software? It should be a free and easy solution.

This would help me a lot to improve workflow and performance. So what I am thinking about, is to run one single system over several physical machines so that I can use pretty all the resources from them.

Comment: A free and easy solution to solve what exact problem? What you heard is wrong, certainly for the workstations. The machines in their rendering farms **combined**, of course matched that 10 years ago. I managed the development of software that was used within ILM (e.g. for StarWars), and that was running on high end Apple machines. Cost is a factor, even for ILM & Co.

Comment: What I am really interessed about, is to combine a lot of physical machines into one big machine (or vm), the solution should be free and linux based..

Comment: AFAIK there are no free machines available, and if there are, please let me know :-). The software is free. So if you have the machines, just hook them up via ethernet and you have one big combined machine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have a link for downloading or tutorials for installation and configuration?

Comment: That's what I am looking for. So that I can connect several machines via ethernet and run one vm over it, so that I have a lot of ram and cores..

Comment: @rudolf97 Maybe check this out: [Beowulf Cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf_cluster)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the ILM systems, but what you're asking for seems to known as a [Single System Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_system_image) cluster.  There have been multiple research Operating Systems, over the years, which attempted to implement this, with varying degrees of success.  Plan 9 is probably the best known candidate there, but it's not Ubuntu.

The Wikipedia link has more details, including links to pages about the various OSes.  I remember hearing, many years ago, about someone using Mosix LiveCDs to turn a computer lab full of networked PCs into an ad-hoc cluster, being able to run one, multi-process task across the bunch of them, then just removing the LiveCDs and rebooting the PCs to get them back to their original use.

Comment: A plan9 cluster seems to be defficult for setting up. The question is if a software like blender will run on it

Comment: To my knowledge, it will not. They would have to port Blender to run on it, as it is a separate Operating System. That's not a trivial task. And, to get the performance benefits of an ad-hoc cluster, they would have to EXTENSIVELY rewrite it as a collection of communicating processes, as that's the development model used on Plan 9.  Most software is NOT written in that fashion so that would be a significant re-design, not just a port.